# Can input exist within a defined function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input

I am trying to shorten the process of making lists through the use of a defined function where the variable is the list name. When run, the code skips the user input.

When I run my code, the section of user input seems to be completely skipped over and as such it just prints an empty list. I've tried messing around with the variable names and defining things at different points in the code. Am I missing a general rule of Python or is there an obvious error in my code I'm missing?

```
def list_creation(list_name):
    list_name = []
    num = 0
    while num != "end":
        return(list_name)
        num = input("Input a number: ")
        print("To end, type end as number input")
        if num != "end":
            list_name.append(num)


list_creation(list_Alpha)

print("This is the first list: " + str(list_Alpha))

list_creation(list_Beta)

print("This is the second list: " + str(list_Beta))
```

I want the two seperate lists to print out the numbers that the user has input. Currently it just prints out two empty lists.

Comment: @I'L'I  Aren't I only clearing list_name the first time I call it? What do you mean I am "immediately returning from it"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the return statement to the end of the function, because return always stops function execution.

Also, what you're trying to do (to my knowledge) is not possible or practical. You can't assign a variable by making it an argument in a function, you instead should remove the parameter `list_name` altogether since you immediately reassign it anyway, and call it like `list_alpha = list_creation()`

As a side note, the user probably wants to see the whole "To end, type end as number input" bit before they start giving input.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of fundamental flaws in your code.

> 1. You redefine `list_name` which is what `Alpha` and `Beta` lists are using as the return.
>    <sub>(`list_name = []` disassociates it with `Alpha` and `Beta` so your function becomes useless.)</sub>
> 2. **You return from the function right after starting your while loop
>    <sub>(so you will never reach the input)</sub>**

In your function:

```
list_Alpha = []
list_Beta = []

def list_creation(list_name):
    # list_name = [] <-- is no longer Alpha or Beta, get rid of this!
    num = 0
    ...
```

The `return` should go at the end of the while loop in order to reach your input:

```
while num != "end":
    num = input("Input a number: ")
    print("To end, type end as number input")
    if num != "end":
        list_name.append(num)
return(list_name)
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue with clearing out Alpha and Beta when I enter the function. Aren't I just creating empty lists with those names?

Comment: You have to define your lists before trying to sending them to a function. You don't show them defined anywhere in your code so you'll get `NameError: name 'list_Alpha' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically defining your variable names is ill advised. With that being said, the following code should do the trick. The problem consisted of a misplaced return statement and confusion of variable name with the variable itself.

```
def list_creation(list_name):
    g[list_name] = []
    num = 0
    while num != "end":
        num = input("Input a number: ")
        print("To end, type end as number input")
        if num != "end":
            g[list_name].append(num)

g = globals()
list_creation('list_Alpha')
print("This is the first list: " + str(list_Alpha))

list_creation('list_Beta')
print("This is the second list: " + str(list_Beta))
```